# underscore - transform an array with _.map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have a multi-dimensional array of objects that I need to transform into a different array. I'm convinced that `_.map()` is what I need. Not having used it before, I'm having trouble traversing the array to extract the correct values. Given this simplified example:

```
[
   {
      "08/25/2015":[
         {
            "source":"someSource0",
            "name":"someName0",
            "stuff":"-6.728479",
            "stuffValue":"14.862200",
            "amount":"-100.00"
         },
         {
            "notNeeded0":-100,
            "subtotal":"-100.00"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "08/26/2015":[
         {
            "source":"someSource1",
            "name":"someName1",
            "stuff":"-9.496676",
            "stuffValue":"10.530000",
            "amount":"-100.00"
         },
         {
            "notNeeded0":-100,
            "subtotal":"-100.00"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "08/27/2015":[
         {
            "source":"someSource2",
            "name":"someName2",
            "stuff":"-9.469697",
            "stuffValue":"10.560000",
            "amount":"-100.00"
         },
         {
            "notNeeded0":-100,
            "subtotal":"-100.00"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "08/28/2015":[
         {
            "source":"someSource3",
            "name":"someName3",
            "stuff":"-1.731841",
            "stuffValue":"10.570000",
            "amount":"-18.24"
         },
         {
            "source":"someSource4",
            "name":"someName4",
            "stuff":"-2.628939",
            "stuffValue":"31.100000",
            "amount":"-81.76"
         },
         {
            "notNeeded0":-100,
            "subtotal":"-100.00"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "notNeeded1":-400,
      "notNeeded2":"-400.00"
   }
]
```

I needed to transform it to something structured like this:

```
[
   {
      "date":"08/27/2015",
      "detail":[
         {
            "source":"someSource2",
            "name":"someName2",
            "stuff":"-9.469697",
            "stuffValue":"10.560000",
            "amount":"-100.00",
            "subtotal":"-100.00"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "date":"08/28/2015",
      "detail":[
         {
            "source":"someSource3",
            "name":"someName3",
            "stuff":"-1.731841",
            "stuffValue":"10.570000",
            "amount":"-18.24",
            "subtotal":"-100.00"
         },
         {
            "source":"someSource4",
            "name":"someName4",
            "stuff":"-2.628939",
            "stuffValue":"31.100000",
            "amount":"-81.76",
            "subtotal":"-100.00"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Please feel free to ask questions if needed. Thanks for your assistance.

EDIT: This code is not for web-based use. So any reference to web and browser compatibility is not necessary. And, I use the underscore library to simplify tasks like looping that can get pretty ugly using pure JS. Hope that clarifies the intent.

Comment: you can use javascript's own *array.[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)(keep_only_dates).[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)(transform)* - unless you need to support IE8

Comment: `.map` is pretty straightforward: The callback is invoked for every element in the array and the return value is added to the new array. The documentation even has examples: http://underscorejs.org/#map .

Comment: @FelixKling i've read the doc first. it's simplified one-level example didn't help me much which is why I posted this question here. It would probably have helped if I had mentioned more about what I've already done. I'll remember that. Thx.

Comment: Oftentimes, I fail to decompose the problem into manageable bits. this example is no different. one solution a colleague proposed is to break out the details (and a totals node not in the OP) and roll them into the final object as evidenced in this updated gist. https://gist.github.com/mjstelly/b7cbfdfc3efda5a90636

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using built-in [.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
var modified = original.filter(function only_nested_arrays(obj) {
  var keys = Object.keys(obj)
  return keys.length === 1 && Array.isArray(obj[keys[0]])
}).map(function transform(obj) {
  var date = Object.keys(obj)[0],
      inner_array = obj[date],
      subtotal = inner_array.splice(-1)[0].subtotal
  inner_array.forEach(function(obj_inner) {
    obj_inner.subtotal = subtotal
  })
  return {date: date, detail: inner_array}
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(modified, null, 2))
```

But watch out for browser compatibility (see the links for a polyfill to make it work on IE8 or lower). Runnable code that alerts the result if you want to test:

```js
"use strict"
var original = [
  {
    "08/25/2015":[
      {
        "source":"someSource0",
        "name":"someName0",
        "stuff":"-6.728479",
        "stuffValue":"14.862200",
        "amount":"-100.00"
      },
      {
        "notNeeded0":-100,
        "subtotal":"-100.00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "08/26/2015":[
      {
        "source":"someSource1",
        "name":"someName1",
        "stuff":"-9.496676",
        "stuffValue":"10.530000",
        "amount":"-100.00"
      },
      {
        "notNeeded0":-100,
        "subtotal":"-100.00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "08/27/2015":[
      {
        "source":"someSource2",
        "name":"someName2",
        "stuff":"-9.469697",
        "stuffValue":"10.560000",
        "amount":"-100.00"
      },
      {
        "notNeeded0":-100,
        "subtotal":"-100.00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "08/28/2015":[
      {
        "source":"someSource3",
        "name":"someName3",
        "stuff":"-1.731841",
        "stuffValue":"10.570000",
        "amount":"-18.24"
      },
      {
        "source":"someSource4",
        "name":"someName4",
        "stuff":"-2.628939",
        "stuffValue":"31.100000",
        "amount":"-81.76"
      },
      {
        "notNeeded0":-100,
        "subtotal":"-100.00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "notNeeded1":-400,
    "notNeeded2":"-400.00"
  }
]

var modified = original.filter(function only_nested_arrays(obj) {
  var keys = Object.keys(obj)
  return keys.length === 1 && Array.isArray(obj[keys[0]])
}).map(function transform(obj) {
  var date = Object.keys(obj)[0],
      inner_array = obj[date],
      subtotal = inner_array.splice(-1)[0].subtotal
  inner_array.forEach(function(obj_inner) {
    obj_inner.subtotal = subtotal
  })
  return {date: date, detail: inner_array}
})

alert(JSON.stringify(modified, null, 2))
```

Comment: I like the JSON `stringify` formatting. I'd forgotten it could do that. It makes it much easier to read.

Comment: caveat: I didn't actually test this on my code. As often happens in business, the development changed directions and we no longer need this algorithm. I wanted to give credit for the assistance. That has intrinsic value to our community. Thanks, @aprillion

Answer (score 0):

Using `_.filter`, `_.map` & `_.chain` here is what it would look like.

```
var transformed = _.chain(data).filter(function (obj) {
    var keys = _.keys(obj);
    // only allow where obj has only one key & the value is an array
    // consider replacing this with a check to see if the key is a date which should be more appropriate
    return keys.length === 1 && _.isArray(obj[keys[0]]);
}).map(function (obj) {
    var date     = _.keys(obj)[0];
    var details  = obj[date];
    var subtotal = details.splice(-1)[0].subtotal; // get the last obj from array destructively
    details      = _.map(details, function (detail) {
        detail.subtotal = subtotal; // append the subtotal to all the remaining detail objects
        return detail
    });
    return {
        date   : date,
        details: details
    }
}).value();
```

I'd suggest that you use the native functions as shown in Aprillion's answer so that you can avoid the whole `chain()` & then `value()` usages for getting the actual value from the wrapped object. You can use underscore when the requirements are a bit more complicated.